# Container complexity

Tags: c++, stl, time-complexity, array-algorithms

Hence I have a `std::set<int>` and `std::list<int>`.
I want to have my container sorted.
For set I will have complexity like `O(nlogn)` for `n` inserted elements.
For list I will have complexity like `O(n)` for insertion of `n` elements + `O(nlogn)` for calling `list::sort`.
In both cases the complexity is `O(nlogn)`, but there is extra `O(n)` operations in case of `std::list`. And I have some constant time for `set` rebalancing.

Here is the question, which container will work faster?

Comment: It's impossible to tell, you need to use a profiler.

Comment: Do you insert elements only once (and then just access them, as you sort list only once) ?

Comment: Yes, once I insert them I start to use without any additional insertion.

Comment: "complexity" it's a word that comes with multiple meanings, there is time complexity, space complexity, worst case complexity, average complexity, amortized complexity ...

Comment: So you may use `std::vector` which is more cache friendly.

Comment: http://bigocheatsheet.com/ to give you an idea

Comment: @Jarod42 but `std::vector` does not have the guarantee about uniqueness and access time that `std::set` has.

Comment: @RedX: see my answer. `std::unique` to remove duplicate, `std::binary_search` to find element.

Answer (score 2):

As you want a '**const**' sorted container, I suggest `std::vector` which is cache friendly.

During initialization:

- `push_back` all elements `O(n)`.
- `std::sort` the vector `O(n log n)`.
- `std::unique` if you want to remove duplicate (as `std::set` does). `O(n)`.

So initialisation is `O(n log n)`.

To check if element exists, use `std::binary_search` to have `O(log n)` instead of `O(n)`.